# Why unidirectional one-to-many association on a foreign key is an unusual case and is not recommended?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

At link http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-m21 it is said that

> **A unidirectional one-to-many association on a foreign key is an unusual case, and is not recommended. Instead the documentation
>   recommends doing a  unidirectional 1-to-M using a join table.**

I am not sure why documentation says it a **unusual case and not recommended**. Because as per my experience it is very common case like customer
can have many account in bank so there will be `one-to-many` relationship between customer and account where customer will be having association
accounts which will be collection of account for that customer.

So why we need to introduce the join table in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What @Alex said was correct. There are two parts to this answer.

I too feel that the case is *not unusual*. However as per your example if a `Customer` has a Collection of `Account` supports the scenario. **However in the example Account CANNOT exist without a Customer.**. Consider another scenario where the collection item  is independent of the Owner.

Let say the relation between `Owner` and `Car`. Owner has many Cars, hence a `one-to-many` relation between `Owner` Entity and `Car` Entity. The database structure would be

```
Owner : [OwnerId, Name...]
Car   : [CarId, Name...., OwnerId]
```

Here we assume that **Car CAN exist without an owner**. In such a condition there will be Car records with `null` OwnerId. Existance of `null` degrades the information. By degrade I mean the quality of information stored is reduced as there are unknowns. The above structure can be re-modeled to

```
 Owner    : [OwnerId, Name...]
 Car      : [CarId, Name....]
 CarOwner : [OwnerId,CarId]
```

Thereby we avoid having `null` valued entries in `Car` and the association between Owner and Car is well defined.

(as @Alex correctly pointed out)
In Hibernate `one-to-many` relation has no recognition of a join table Hence we use `many-to-many` with `unique` flag set to true to map the relation. *However mind you introducing a join table will unnecessarily increase the number of joins.*

*Hope this explaination helps.*

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=957582&highlight=foriegn%20foreign%20key%20nullable) on the Hibernate Forums.

The reason is that your mapping declares that the many side of the relationship knows nothing about its parent. However in database terms that entity has the foreign key to the one side and does know about its parent. Therefore your mapping and database structure do not agree.

Having a join table eliminates that mismatch.

Comment: hey alex, i just tried one to many relationship without join table like person to phone having 1 to many relationship. I was successfuly save  and retrieve the association  as collection.Not sure  what is the problem with 1 to many relationship without join table. Could you give brief scenario where its an issue and join table does help

Comment: Hibernate will support your design. They're just pointing out that it's non consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
table customer(id, idAccount)

id  |  idAccount
1         1
1         2
```

With a join table:

```
table customer(id)

id |
 1

table join (idCustomer, idAccount)

idCustomer  | idAccount
     1            1
     1            2
```

Retrieving the `Customer` would produce only one row. Since the `Customer` pojo would be mapped to a `customer` in db.